# How is the 6th bit of the DSCP-field called?

Tags: qos

RFC 2474 uses the ToS byte for Differentiated Services Code Point:

```
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 |      DSCP field       |CU/ECN | 
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Further, the DSCP field has more divisions:

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   Class   |  Drop | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|___________ ___________|
            V
      DSCP field
```

My question is now, HOW is the 6. bit, the bit with the number 5, called? The only thing I know is that it is 0. But no name or anything for the 6. Bit. I'm reading the book 'Deploying QoS for cisco IP and Next-Generation-Networks' and there is where I found the table.

The same ToS Byte is also (and originally) used for IP Precedence (RFC 791), and there every bit is described and named:

```
  0 + 1 + 2     3         4          5             6  +  7
+-----------+-------+----------+-----------+--------------------+
|Precedence | Delay |Throughput|Reliability|Reserved and unused |
+-----------+-------+----------+-----------+--------------------+
```

I need this for further understanding of how QoS works and how the mapping from IP-Precedence-to-DSCP works.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, I'd say that 6 doesn't have a name as it is CU, or Currently Unused.